How do I connect my refrigerator water line to a Reverse Osmosis System?
I purchased an iSpring RCC1D Tankless RO/DI System, but none of the connectors work with the water line going to the refrigerator. What kind of part do I need to connect the out tube from the RO system to the water line? (I can't replace the line going to the fridge as it runs under the kitchen floor)
Existing water line to the fridge:

Connectors I got with the RO system:

